# GridView Column Sizes not Changing ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to increase the size of one of my columns in my gridview, however, no matter how i try to increase the size, the column width fails to increase. The data for the GridView is being retrieved in my c# code which grabs the data from my database. I check my Css code for the gridview class and nothing seems to affect the width of the column (Or at least I think). Why wont my columns width change?

This is my setup currently:
ASP.NET:

```
 <div id="grid" style="overflow-x: auto; margin: auto; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100px; text-align: center;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="empty" Font-Size="15px" Font-Bold="True" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="lessonsgrid" CssClass="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="1%" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" DataField="Id" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Release" SortExpression="Release" DataField="Release" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" DataField="Category" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%"  HeaderText="Subcategory" SortExpression="Subcategory" DataField="Subcategory" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-CssClass="descriptionCol" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" DataField="Description" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%"  HeaderText="Identifying Team" SortExpression="Identifying Team" DataField="Identifying Team" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="5%"  HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" DataField="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Suggestions For Improvement" SortExpression="Suggestions For Improvement" DataField="Suggestions For Improvement" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="5%"  HeaderText="Team Assigned To" SortExpression="Team Assigned To" DataField="Team Assigned To" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="5%"  HeaderText="Implemented" SortExpression="Implemented" DataField="Implemented" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="5%"  HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="Priority" DataField="Priority" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="5%"  HeaderText="Implement Complexity" SortExpression="Implement Complexity" DataField="Implement Complexity" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%"  HeaderText="Target Implement Date" SortExpression="Target Implement Date" DataField="Target Implement Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Comment" DataField="Comment" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

Css .gridview:

```
.gridview a:link {
    color: #0043bd;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.gridview a:visited {
    color: #0043bd;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.gridview a:active,
.gridview a:hover {
    color: #bd5a35;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.gridview {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    background: #eaebec;
    margin: 20px;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
}

    .gridview th {
        padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        background: #ededed;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed, #ebebeb);
    }

        .gridview th:first-child {
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

    .gridview tr:first-child th:first-child {
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    }

    .gridview tr:first-child th:last-child {
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    }

    .gridview tr {
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .gridview td:first-child {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 20px;
        border-left: 0;
    }

    .gridview td {
        padding: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        background: #fafafa;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb, #fafafa);
    }

    .gridview tr.even td {
        background: #f6f6f6;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#f6f6f6));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #f6f6f6);
    }

    .gridview tr:last-child td {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }

        .gridview tr:last-child td:first-child {
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        }

        .gridview tr:last-child td:last-child {
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
        }

    .gridview tr:hover td {
        background: #f2f2f2;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#f0f0f0));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2f2f2, #f0f0f0);
    }
```

Comment: One column has 204%.

Comment: yes, that was me trying to see if there would be any change, unfortunate not.

Comment: If content in table are too much, columns become too tight and they won't be able to apply the width the you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i cant add a comment yet but  you are using percentages on all elements.  There needs to be an element with an actual fixed width.  That way the percentages know what percentage of that width to take up.

Comment: I changed the id column with to 50px, yet nothing happened.

Comment: See if setting a width on the div id="grid" to something like 800px does the trick.

Comment: nope nothing, i set the div to 1000px, but nothing happened to the column widths.

Comment: Just noticed i didn't see any width attributes on your grid view itself.  !00% or fixed value.

Comment: I had the gridview width to 100% and i tried 1060px. But that too had no effect.